# Wrong placing of a linked framework in project structure

Tags: ios, frameworks, targets

**Hi**,

I've a maybe really simple question to you. According to [Apple's tip how to link to a framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html), I tried to add some frameworks to my project.

All works fine, **BUT** the **frameworks are added at the top of my project structure** which is, in my opinion, somehow annoying because there exists already a framework subfolder. But if I drag&drop the linked "framework" to this folder, the framework appears red in my target's "Link Binary With Library" window. So XCode is missing the right location.

Can somebody explain me, how to move the framework or in general add the framework in the framework subfolder?!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just closing XCode and restarting it. I've had the same problem, and did the same thing you did - dragged the frameworks into the "Frameworks" folder where they belong. They turn red, but when I close and reopen Xcode, they're no longer red, and I'm able to build and run as usual.